# Add foreach to function

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to edit a wordpress php file with the following function :

```
add_action('userpro_after_profile_head','userpro_sc_bar', 99);
    function userpro_sc_bar( $args ) {
        global $userpro, $userpro_social;
        extract($args);

        ( display content buttons here )
}
```

I am trying to add a button to this function from a different plugin and I need to add the following global rules :

```
foreach ( $sellers['users'] as $seller ) {
                    $store_info = get_store_info( $seller->ID );
                    $store_url  = get_store_url( $seller->ID );
}
```

When I add the two lines `$store_info` and `$store_url` to the global rules, it works, but I'm not getting the $seller ID that is defined with the `foreach` argument

When I add the whole thing into the global rules like this :

```
add_action('userpro_after_profile_head','userpro_sc_bar', 99);
    function userpro_sc_bar( $args ) {
        global $userpro, $userpro_social;
        extract($args);
           foreach ( $sellers['users'] as $seller ) {
                    $store_info = get_store_info( $seller->ID );
                    $store_url  = get_store_url( $seller->ID );
           }
                   ( display content buttons here )
    }
```

It is no longer working.

It there a proper to combine these 2 together ??

Comment: Don't use `extract()`, ever. It is unreliable and causes a lot of errors. This function is already being removed from core, and it seems it might be dropped in php as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with wordpress...
but could this be an issue with the `$sellers` variable?

I think the `$sellers` variable is not accessible from within your function.

Assuming `$sellers` is a global variable you could try:

```
add_action('userpro_after_profile_head','userpro_sc_bar', 99);
    function userpro_sc_bar( $args ) {
        global $userpro, $userpro_social, $sellers; // <-- Added $sellers
        extract($args);
           foreach ( $sellers['users'] as $seller ) {
                    $store_info = get_store_info( $seller->ID );
                    $store_url  = get_store_url( $seller->ID );
           }
                   ( display content buttons here )
    }
```

Comment: Well, is the $sellers variable accessible from within your function?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with php, how can check if it is accessible from within the function ?

Comment: I would look into [Debugging in Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).

Normally I would say just `var_dump($sellers)` or `print_r($sellers)` and look for the output in a page that uses the function. However, I don't know if that would work in this case.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot, i'll look into it .. also something like this for example `$sellers = get_sellers( );`  doesn't it define the $sellers in the function ?

Comment: If i had more information, maybe I could give you an answer. I don't have enough information to tell you what functions or variables are even available to you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got is ,this works for me :

```
add_action('userpro_after_profile_head','userpro_sc_bar', 99);
    function userpro_sc_bar( $args ) {
        global $userpro, $userpro_social, $sellers; // <-- Added $sellers
        extract($args);
        $sellers = get_sellers(); // <-- Get $sellers
           foreach ( $sellers['users'] as $seller ) {
                    $store_info = get_store_info( $seller->ID );
                    $store_url  = get_store_url( $seller->ID );
           }
                   ( display content buttons here )
    }
```